# Python/Matplotlib - Set Colorbar for multiple scatter plots on same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm using Python and Matplotlib to add a variable number of scatter plots to a figure. Each scatter plot is a series and I want to color each scatter trace's points by their sequence index numbers. However, since my sequences have different length, I want 1 consistent colorbar for all the sequences.

I can keep track on the min and max sequence length. But how do I use this information to configure the colorbar to represent this complete range?

Comment: Pass the same vmin and vmax to each scatter call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it is not completely clear how the data looks like.
Here is an example using 4 series with different lengths, all having an index `0,1,2,3,...`. The scatter plots the index versus the value, and colors each series using the full color range.

The proposal is to add one colorbar per series, provided there aren't too many. Each colorbar has a title and shows ticks depending on the range used for that series. Making the colorbars (except the first) very narrow makes them look like an additional ax.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 4
series_to_plot = [pd.Series(np.random.uniform(i, i + 0.8, np.random.randint(50, 400))) for i in range(1, N + 1)]
names = [f'data{i}' for i in range(1, N + 1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
for ind, (ser, name) in enumerate(zip(series_to_plot, names)):
    scat = ax.scatter(ser.index, ser, c=ser.index, s=1, cmap='plasma')
    cax = fig.add_axes(
        [1 - (N - ind) * 0.05, 0.1, 0.01 if ind == 0 else 0.002, 0.75])  # left, bottom, width, height, where 1,1 is top right of the fig
    cbar = fig.colorbar(scat, cax=cax)
    cax.set_title(name)

plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.97 - N * 0.05)  # make room for the colorbars
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]